Mongodb is not connecting to Node.js and no error messages
I'm new to Node.js and MongoDB. I installed all packages as specified in a YouTube tutorial.  I tried a lot to connect MongoDB with Node.js, but there is no error messages and it is not connected. I have downloaded Mongo Shell as well. Everything works perfectly, the connection message is not displayed. It works on my command prompt, but not in vs code. I'm creating a sample project with Express generator. What's wrong with my code?
Here is my code:
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient


/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

router.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);


  MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017', function(err, client){
    if(err)
      console.log('error')
    else
      console.log('mongodb connected...')
  })

  
  res.send('Got it.')
})


Print proper error message like console.log(err) instead of a static text 'error'

@WernfriedDomscheit There is no error messages. The post method consoles properly. But the system acting like I didn't added the MongoDB connecting code (:

copy your mongodb connect to a new file and run it directly and see if there is anything. Beside, I just look at the documents on npm and found that this is very different from the example of official docs

Try my simple code below, if it works, it says "Connected successfully to server" in the console log. It is only the first step.
//const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
// or as an es module:
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const client = new MongoClient(url);

// Database Name
const dbName = 'myProject';

async function main() {
    // Use connect method to connect to the server
    await client.connect();
    console.log('Connected successfully to server');
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    const collection = db.collection('documents');

   
    return 'done.';
}

main()
    .then(console.log)
    .catch(console.error)
    .finally(() => client.close());

Try to install the mongodb driver again using this file package.json content:
 {
  "name": "mongodb",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "mongodbsort.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "mongodb": "^4.17.2"    
  }
}

the row  "type": "module",  is important

I got the the message 'connected' in my terminal. Thanks...

But I got an error message when I try to start mongosh in terminal     'Current Mongosh Log ID: 
Connecting to:          mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+2.3.2
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017'. what it means ?

Sorry i don't use 'mongosh' in my terminal.  I use 'mongo'  terminal client app, but previously I started the server with this row (without password):  sudo mongod --noauth --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb       ***** noauth is for starting without password  ***

Okay bro, I don't know what was the error. I deleted MongoDB and reinstalled. Now everything works perfectly. Thanks for your time :).
